A consideration of the mathematical tools that contributed to the birth of Fubini's theorem
I posted a question about the history of Fubini's theorem on the History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange. The answer to this question was also really helpful to me, but I wanted to dig a little deeper into Fubini's theorem, so I decided to post the question.
From a combination of Wikipedia and answers on the History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange, we can see that Pringsheim presented prototypes of both the double integral and the double series versions of Fubini's theorem.


Double Integral version $${\displaystyle \,\iint \limits _{X\times Y}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}(x,y)=\int _{X}\left(\int _{Y}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}y\right){\text{d}}x=\int _{Y}\left(\int _{X}f(x,y)\,{\text{d}}x\right){\text{d}}y.}$$

Double Series version $${\displaystyle \sum _{(m,n)\in \mathbb {N} \times \mathbb {N} }a_{m,n}=\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }a_{m,n}=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }a_{m,n}}$$



If you read the contents of pp.154-159 in Hawkins Thomas' book, Lebesgue's theory of integration: its origins and development, In particular, if you read p.158,

servation that suggested to Fubini the possibility of improving Theorem 5.16: If the function $f$ of Theorem 5.16 is Borel-measurable that is, if for every real number a the set of points $(z,y)$ such that $f(x,y) > a$ is Borel-measurable then the functions $z→f(x,y)$ and $y→f(z,y)$ are also Borel-measurable. (Here Lebesgue made use of the fact that the intersection of a planar Borel-measurable set and a line parallel to one of the coordinate axes is a linear Borél-measurable set.) Hence for Borel-measurable functions, the upper and lower integrals in Theorem 5.16 can be replaced by ordinary Lebesgue integrals. In the paper [1906] in which Hobson treated de la Vallée-Poussin's notion of regular convergence, he also put the difficulties encountered by de la Vallée-Poussin in a new light. If (in the notation of Hobson's version of Fubini's Theorem) $\underline{I}_n=\bar{I}_n$ and $\underline{I}=\bar{I}$, then the generalized definition of regular convergence becomes Arzelà's necessary and sufficient condition that $I(y)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}I_n(y)$ satisfy Riemann's integrability condition $(R_2)$ (without the additional condition that $I(y)$ be finite valued or bounded). In other words, it is precisely the fact that this integrability condition is not always preserved in the limit that is behind the difficulties encountered by de la Vallée-Poussin.

If you look at p.93 of An Introduction to the theory of Infinite series by Bromwich, you will see the following passage:

It must not, however, be supposed that the condition of Mertens is necessary for the convergence of $\sum{c_n}$ ; in fact Pringsheim has established a large number of results on the multiplication of two series, neither of which converges absolutely.

If you read Ueber Doppelfolgen und Doppelreihen, you will see the following sentence on the first page:

Eine Folge einfacher Zahlenfolgen:
$$\begin{matrix}
a_0^{(0)}& a_1^{(0)}& a_2^{(0)}&...\\
a_0^{(1)}& a_1^{(1)}& a_2^{(1)}&...\\
a_0^{(2)}& a_1^{(2)}& a_2^{(2)}&...\\
...
\end{matrix}$$
bezeichnen wit als eine zweifach unendliche Zahlenfolge oder kurz als
,,Doppdfolge" und denken ihre Elemente stets in der oben angegebenen
Weise in Zeilen und Colonnen angeordnet. Dis Doppelfolgen bflden die
Orundlage fiir die Theorie der Doplelreihen Doppelproducte $u. s. w.$, sowie wichiger Eigenschaflen der Funcionen zweier Variabeln, und es is ihr
Sudium deshalb wichtig, weil sie das Charakeristische der bei diesen
Gebflden in Frage kommenden Verhltnisse besonders deuflich hervorbremen lassen*). Ausser yon Herrn Pringsheim, welcher im ersen Paragraphen seiner Arbeit fiber die unendliehen Dopelreihen**) einige grandlegende Eigenschafen der Doppelfolgen herleie, sind die Doppelfolgen
meines Wissens nicht zum Gegenande sines directen Shldiums gemacht
worden.

Above sentence is German. So I traslated it to english.

A sequence of simple number sequences:
$$\begin{matrix}
a_0^{(0)}& a_1^{(0)}& a_2^{(0)}&...\\
a_0^{(1)}& a_1^{(1)}& a_2^{(1)}&...\\
a_0^{(2)}& a_1^{(2)}& a_2^{(2)}&...\\
...
\end{matrix}$$
We refer to it as a doubly infinite number sequence or, for short, as a "double sequence" and think of its elements as arranged in rows and columns in the manner given above. The double sequences provide the basis for the theory of double series, double products
$u, s, w$, as well as important properties of the functions of two variables, and their study is important because they reveal the characteristics of the functions in question in these structures. relationships can be brought out particularly clearly*). Apart from Mr. Pringsheim, who in the first paragraph of his work on infinite double series**) describes some of the most important properties of double sequences, double sequences have not, to my knowledge, been made the subject of a direct comparison.

If you read the English translation above, you will see that the study of double sequence is important because it not only forms the basis for theories such as double multiplication, but also explains important properties of functions of two variables. So I wondered if Pringsheim had this in mind.
Based on the above materials, I think that Borel-measurable and condition of Mertens were the tools that filled the mathematical gap at the time that allowed Fubini and Pringsheim to come up with the mathematical content that is now called Fubini's theorem. Is this thought process correct? And if not, what did Fubini and Pringsheim base on to come up with the theorem that is now called Fubini's theorem?
Edit: I found Development of mathematics in the 19th century by Felix Klein. If you read p. 250 of this book, you will see that Fubini is one of the people who came up with a general proof for the Riemann Existence theorem. So I wondered if this might have been the motivation for Fubini's theorem.
